# Cannot find Xorg.conf in Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: xorg, xubuntu

For some resolution reasone, i need to use custom edid.bin. As i know, it can be configure in Xorg.conf, but there is

Answer (score 2):

By default no `xorg.conf` file is used in Ubuntu, and the X layout is autodetected at boot. However, if you create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, any settings contained should be used.